# Custom library gives "no package found"

Tags: java

I decided to make a custom .jar library just for the hell of it.

It's insanely basic, it's package name is "add" and looks like this:

```
public class addtogether{
      public void addtogether(int a, int b, int c){
      c=a+b
      }}
```

So I try importing it in a file, by doing this:

```
public class test{
import add.*;
public static void main (String[]        args){
int x;
add(4,5,x);
System.out.println(x);
}
}
```

and surprise surprise! No package found.

I did the whole dance of adding it to the IDE in the preferences section, but it still doesn't work.

help please.

Comment: A) follow naming conventions, such as classes starting Upper case, and methods using camelCase B) is that your full class? If so, consider adding a **package** statement. You should not use the default (unnamed) package.

Comment: What you see is what my library consists of. That's it. So, what do I do to fix it? I'm a noob if you can't tell, so I don't know left from right.

Comment: Step by step: you could use the jar command line tool to check what is *inside* the jar you generated. The next question is. what do you mean by *import* it?

Comment: import jarname.*;

Comment: You have to understand what you are doing. That **import** statement (if used in java source code) doesn't import a JAR name. It looks for a package called jarname. Therefore, again: you start by adding a package statement to your initial class. Then you verify that the JAR file you create contains a folder that matches the package name, and in that folder, you have a file AddTogetherExample.class (after giving your class a reasonable name). Then you would `import yourpackage.*` for example. Don't *invent* things. Read documentation, and follow it.

Comment: Like: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html  and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/index.html

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood. There are many things I could call the adding library .jar file, so I said "jarname" in my comment. If I decided to name it "addmystufftogether.jar" I would do   import addmystufftogether.*;

Comment: No, thats wrong. It doesn't matter what your jar name is. You need to mention your package inside the jar in the import statement. Suppose you have the package like "com.arithemetic" and the util class is inside it, then you need to mention import com.arithmetic.* or import com.arithmetic.UtilClassName.

Comment: so if I add com. to the beginning it will fix it?

Comment: Mentioned the edits in my answer hope it makes sense.

Comment: No. You stop inventing stuff. You have to study the links I gave you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very naive step by step implementation for using a custom jar:

1. Create a java project with a utility class containing your functionality. (You can use the class defined above.) Example: (Project Name: ArithmeticUtility, Jar Name : ArithmeticUtility.jar, Package name: com.arithmetic, ClassName: Calculator)
2. Export it as a jar.
3. Create another java project add the jar by right clicking on the project-> Build Path-> Configure Build Path->Add External jars-> Apply-> Ok.
4. Use the class in your present project by mentioning the required imports. (Example: import com.arithmetic.*)

Please edit your code as below:

```
import add.*; // import statements should be at top after package outside 
public class test{
public static void main (String[] args){
int x;
addTogether testObj=new addTogether();
int result=testObj.add(4,5);
System.out.println("Result: "+result);
}}


public class AddTogether{
public void addtogether(int a, int b){
return a+b; // your method has no return statement
}}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ok, so I created a package called add and at the beginning of my library file, I put "package add;" And then in my testing file I imported add.*; and it still wont do anything

Comment: What do you mean by "wont do anything". Could you please be clear what is the issue? Are you facing issue in importing the class "addtogether"?

Comment: add.* does not exist

Comment: Are you sure your jar is fine (your jar has the package and class within it), and check in the test project by going to (Right Click->Build Path-> Configure Build path->Libraries) if the jar is present.

Comment: Unzip the jar using WinZip,7-Zip or any such tools in your local directory and check for the package and class files.

Comment: Ok, progress! It detects the package! But, sadly, now it says "cannot find symbol method add (int,int,int)

Comment: Can you edit your question using the code from the test class where you are accessing the method add(int,int,int)

Comment: Thank you. I read your answer more closely and changed it from add to addclass.add. It works. Is there some way I can repay you for your help?

Comment: No this platform is for this purpose. But I will strongly recommend you to go through the java tutorials available online. Keep Learning. :)